# Spring amqp - no compatible authentication mechanism found - server offered []

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm trying to connect spring boot app to rabbit mq through EXTERNAL auth mechanism (https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-auth-mechanism-ssl).

I get following error:

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException: No compatible authentication mechanism found - server offered []
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:70) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:594) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:687) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:257) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2225) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2198) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2178) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueInfo(RabbitAdmin.java:459) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:443) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.attemptDeclarations(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1891) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1858) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.initialize(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1384) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1230) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No compatible authentication mechanism found - server offered []
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:343) ~[amqp-client-5.17.0.jar:5.17.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1225) ~[amqp-client-5.17.0.jar:5.17.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1173) ~[amqp-client-5.17.0.jar:5.17.0]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connectAddresses(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:632) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:607) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:557) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
```

RabbitMq version: rabbitmq:3.12.1-management

rabbitmq.conf contains those properties:

```
default_user=guest
default_pass=guest
listeners.tcp=none
listeners.ssl.default=5672
ssl_options.cacertfile=/etc/rabbitmq/cert/ca_bundle.pem
ssl_options.certfile=/etc/rabbitmq/cert/certificate.pem
ssl_options.keyfile=/etc/rabbitmq/cert/key.pem
ssl_options.password=pass
ssl_options.verify=verify_peer
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert=true
ssl_options.versions.1=tlsv1.2
ssl_options.depth=1
auth_mechanisms.1=EXTERNAL
ssl_cert_login_from=common_name
```

application.properties:

```
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.enabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.algorithm=TLSv1.2
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.key-store=keystore.p12
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.key-store-password=pass
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.trust-store=truststore.p12
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.trust-store-password=pass
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.trust-store-type=PKCS12
```

I declared following method to include sasl config:

```
  @Bean
  public AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = (CachingConnectionFactory) connectionFactory;
    cachingConnectionFactory.getRabbitConnectionFactory().setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);
    cachingConnectionFactory.getRabbitConnectionFactory().setSaslConfig(DefaultSaslConfig.EXTERNAL);
    cachingConnectionFactory.resetConnection();

    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(converter());
    return rabbitTemplate;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is `listeners.ssl.default=5672` on the RabbitMQ configuration side, but sounds like you override a default SSL port to that one.

The logic in Spring Boot is like this:

```
return (Optional.ofNullable(getSsl().getEnabled()).orElse(false)) ? DEFAULT_PORT_SECURE : DEFAULT_PORT;
```

Where:

```
private static final int DEFAULT_PORT_SECURE = 5671;
```

So, probably need to look into providing that port explicitly:

```
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
```

You also might not need that custom `RabbitTemplate` bean and just add a `ConnectionFactoryCustomizer` to setup that `DefaultSaslConfig.EXTERNAL` into an auto-configured `com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory`.

It is also not recommended to use `setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true)`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/amqp/connections.html#auto-recovery

Comment: I changed listeners.ssl.default to 5671 and added the bean:


  @Bean
  public ConnectionFactoryCustomizer connectionFactoryCustomizer() {
    return connectionFactory -> connectionFactory.setSaslConfig(DefaultSaslConfig.EXTERNAL);
  }

The error is still the same. I have to keep RabbitTemplate bean in order to set message converter.

Comment: You also don't need to set that converter manually: just provide such a bean and Spring Boot takes care for you about the proper injection. I cannot help with SSL config. Probably you can share with us a simple Spring Boot app to reproduce the problem? I see you have mentioned `rabbitmq:3.12.1-management` - sounds like Testcontainers...

Comment: Ok, I removed RabbitTemplate bean declaration. I'm not using this version of rabbitmq in TestContainers. TLS configuration works properly for not EXTERNAL auth mechanism. What i want to achieve is authentication by common name. I already created user through management api with same login as certificate CN.

Comment: So, SSL configuration and connections works well, unless you add that `DefaultSaslConfig.EXTERNAL`? Then I would like to learn more about this stuff. Any chances to know where to go about this kind of configuration?

Comment: It works well unless I add those props in rabbit.conf file :
auth_mechanisms.1=EXTERNAL
ssl_cert_login_from=common_name

Comment: Can you confirm somehow, please, that it works OK with the plain RabbitMQ Java Client? When there is no Spring involved at all. I mean this might be a time to seek help from RabbitMQ team bit itself: https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users

Comment: Thanks for help. It turned out I had to enable rabbit plugin (rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl) in enabled_plugins file.